# get duplicated items in listvalue when I call DownloadJSON AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I load JSON file and fill it to `listview` with `DownloadJSON` `AsyncTask`,
but if i call  `DownloadJSON` `AsyncTask` after for update my `listview` with new 
row , I get duplicate items. This my `DownloadJSON` `AsyncTask`.

```
 // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Load orders from server");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create an array
        arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address

        jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://www.xxxxxx.com/restaurant/ecommerce/api/orders.php?accesskey=12345");
        try {
            // Locate the array name in JSON
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("orders");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                GroupItem item = new GroupItem();
                GroupItem itemdone = new GroupItem();

                if(jsonobject.getInt("Status")==0){
                    item.title = jsonobject.getString("name");
                    item.tabletitle = jsonobject.getString("table_");
                    item.order_id= jsonobject.getString("id");
                    item.status_="0";
                    String str_order=jsonobject.getString("order_items_title");
                    StringTokenizer result_ = new StringTokenizer(str_order,"||");

                    while (result_.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String[] order_price=result_.nextToken().split("\\*");
                        ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
                        child.title =order_price[0];
                        child.hint = order_price[1];
                        item.items.add(child);
                    }
                    ChildItem child = new ChildItem(); 
                    child.title =jsonobject.getString("note");
                    item.items.add(child);
                    items.add(item);


                }else if(jsonobject.getInt("Status")==1){
                    item.status_="1";
                     itemdone.title = jsonobject.getString("name");
                    itemdone.order_id= jsonobject.getString("id");
                    itemdone.tabletitle = jsonobject.getString("table_");
                    String str_order=jsonobject.getString("order_items_title");
                    StringTokenizer result_ = new StringTokenizer(str_order,"||");

                    while (result_.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String[] order_price=result_.nextToken().split("\\*");
                        ChildItem child = new ChildItem();
                        child.title =order_price[0];

                        child.hint = order_price[1];
                        itemdone.items.add(child);
                    }
                    ChildItem child = new ChildItem(); 
                    child.title =jsonobject.getString("note");
                    itemdone.items.add(child);
                    itemsdone.add(itemdone);

                }


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {


        adapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        adapter.clear();
        adapter.setData(items);

        listView = (AnimatedExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



        adapterdone = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        adapterdone.clear();
        adapterdone.setData(itemsdone);

        listViewdone = (AnimatedExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdone);
        listViewdone.setAdapter(adapterdone);

        // In order to show animations, we need to use a custom click handler
        // for our ExpandableListView.
        listView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                if (listView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    listView.collapseGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                } else {
                    listView.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

       listViewdone.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                if (listViewdone.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                    listViewdone.collapseGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                } else {
                    listViewdone.expandGroupWithAnimation(groupPosition);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });


        ////////////////////////////////

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}





private static class GroupItem {
    String title;
    String order_id;
    String tabletitle;
    String status_;
    List<ChildItem> items = new ArrayList<ChildItem>();
}

private static class ChildItem {
    String title;
    String hint;
}

private static class ChildHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView hint;
}

private static class GroupHolder {
    TextView title;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    public TextView tabletitle;
}
```

Comment: What's getting duplicated? You can clear the lists inside onPreExecute() method.

Comment: how i can clear list and fill it ?

Comment: For example call itemdone.items.clear() inside onPreExecute() method. I'm just assuming here because I haven't seen your adapter class.

Comment: call 'adapter.notifydatasetChanged()' after set adapter.